# Specifying the JSON name for protobuf extension

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I've added an extending message to a message and need to marshal it as a json. However the field name for the extension message is `[message.extension_message_name]`.

I would prefer it to be named just `extension_message_name`, without the braces and prefix, since this extension message exists elsewhere in our API and and having this weird name adds confusion.

As far as I can tell the bit of code responsible is in [protobuf/jsonpb](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/jsonpb/jsonpb.go#L256), where the JSONName is set with `fmt.Sprintf("[%s]", desc.Name` and cannot be overwritten it seems.

Anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 13):

As per the [language guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json):

> Message field names are mapped to lowerCamelCase and become JSON object keys. If the json_name field option is specified, the specified value will be used as the key instead.

So tagging your field with `json_name` should do the trick, for example this:

```
message TestMessage {
    string myField = 1 [json_name="my_special_field_name"];
}
```

Should make `myField` have the name `my_special_field_name` when marshalled to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some options but that's because none of them are good:

1. Create a new struct with different json struct tags and then use reflection to overlay one struct onto the other.
2. Use https://github.com/favadi/protoc-go-inject-tag to inject custom struct tags, but you'll probably find that you need to use a different tag then json to avoid conflicts and then find a json library that allows for a custom struct tag
3. Rewrite the json bytes after you marshaled it to find and replace in the stringified text.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to use Go's `encoding/json` package and a tagged struct to decode/marshal the json yourself, something like this:

```
type Example struct {
    ExtMessageName string `json:"extension_message_name"`
}

msg := Example{ExtMessageName: "This is a test"}

jsonBytes, err := json.Marshal(msg)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    return
}

fmt.Println(string(jsonBytes))
```

[example on play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/qXNaXWoKyF5)

which then outputs:

```
{"extension_message_name":"This is a test"}
```