# How to cast/convert nested Struct to Protobuf?

Tags: go, struct, protocol-buffers, proto

I am working on a personal project & using Go for the first time. I am using structs for operating on the data and for storing the data in a file, I am using proto as the encoder.

In the project, my proto definition looks something like this:

```
message AssetPairInfo {
    string Altname = 1;
    string AssetClassBase = 2;
    string Base = 3;
    .... Additional fields
}

message AssetPairsResponse {
  AssetPairInfo ADACAD = 1;
  AssetPairInfo ADAETH = 2;
  AssetPairInfo ADAEUR = 3;
  ... Additional fields
}
```

My struct looks like this:

```
type AssetPairInfo struct {
    Altname string `json:"altname"`
    AssetClassBase string `json:"aclass_base"`
    Base string `json:"base"`
    ... Additional fields
}

type AssetPairsResponse struct {
    ADACAD   AssetPairInfo
    ADAETH   AssetPairInfo
    ADAEUR   AssetPairInfo
    ... Additional fields
}
```

I included only 3 definitions from each struct but my structs have more than 70 definitions..
I'm looking for a programatic way to cast the AssetPairsResponse struct to my protobuf. Given the fact my struct and protobuf are sharing the same fields (except the additional generated protobuf fields), it seems like it should be possible to do.

Any idea?

Comment: if you are representing your data using proto messages, then why are you writitng the structs yourself? the protoc compiler itself will generate the structs for you and you should only use those, there will be no need to case one struct to another struct, right?

Comment: The structs are defined by an external API library I'm using. The data from the API is received in the manner it is defined. I then recreated a proto definition to be able to send that data via gRPC

Comment: In that case, there is no point using proto, right? coz your communication with external API would anyway happen with JSON request, and you will be unnecessarily casting it to proto objects and then write business logic on it (which would give no benefit in terms of performance). Possibilities: 1)Either ask the external service to use proto for better application performance 2) stick with JSON only 3) in case you wish to migrate to proto in the future then there only do the conversion, for conversion you can get libraries online, eg: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb

Answer (score 2):

As workaround, if the model (your custom and the proto message) share the same json tag name, you could unmarshal your custom struct and then marshal the proto message. As example:

```
myModel := model.AssetPairsResponse{
....
}

b, err := json.Marshal(myModel)


myProto := &pb.AssetPairsResponse{}


json.Unmarshal(b, myProto)
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work by changing my proto message naming to conform with the custom json tag names. It is not ideal though, because the field names are changed in the process. Is there an option to set the json tag names without changing the field name?

Comment: You could try as described here: [Specifying the JSON name for protobuf extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428691/specifying-the-json-name-for-protobuf-extension)

Comment: I came across this question and already tried the first answer's suggestion but it doesn't work for Unmarshaling. Whenever I Unmarshal a json into a proto message, the fields are not transformed properly, hence the data is lost.