# How to name these Google Protobuf fields so I can use them in GoLang to accept specific JSON?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am building a gRPC function (called myFunc) that takes the equivalent of the following JSON data as its argument:

```
{
  "id": "ABCD4435010",
  "otherId": "WXYZ4435010",
  "duration": 30
}
```

As part of this exercise, I need to design the protobuf message. It looks like this:

```
 1:    // MyFunc does something I guess.
 2:    rpc MyFunc(MyFuncRequest) returns (MyFuncResponse) {
 3:        option (google.api.http) = {
 4:            post: "/my.path.to.endpoint/MyFunc"
 5:            body: "*"
 6:        };
 7:    }
 8:
 9:    // MyFuncRequest is the request object for MyFunc.
10:    message MyFuncRequest {
11:        // id is something.
12:        string id = 1;
13:        // otherId is something.
14:        string otherId = 2;
15:        // duration is something.
16:        string duration = 3;
17:    }
```

When I try to generate the golang files from this, I get the following errors:

```
myFile.proto:14:3:Field name "otherId" must be lower_snake_case.
myFile.proto:16:3:Field "duration" must be a google.protobuf.Duration.
```

2 problems with these errors:

1. If I change `otherId` to `other_id` it will no longer match the key name in the JSON.
2. If I change `duration` field's type to `google.protobuf.Duration` it will no longer match the type of data from the JSON. So that marshalling/unmarshalling will fail.

How can I work around these error messages and get my protocol buffers to compile?

Comment: what is your go grpc client library?

Answer (score 0):

follow the grpc quick start guide for Go in there website(`protoc version 3`) [grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/)

By updating their `hello world` example as saying [here](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/#update-the-grpc-service) change that HelloRequest as follow and regenerate grpc code following [this command](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/#regenerate-grpc-code).

```
    message HelloRequest {
        // id is something.
        string id = 1;
        // otherId is something.
        string otherId = 2;
        // duration is something.
        string duration = 3;
    }
```

regenerate command

```
    --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    helloworld/helloworld.proto
```

It will create grpc request with your fields without an error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're getting `OtherId` and you want `otherId`.

It may be easiest to create a new type and map this to|from the proto-generated types. This gives you the desired mapping without having to do any 'acrobatics' to keep `protoc` happy and get the JSON you want.

I'm surprised, it detects and forces `duration`. You want this to be a number rather than a string. Have you tried using e.g. `uint32` in your message definition instead of `string` (which it isn't)?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Specifying the JSON name for protobuf extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428691/specifying-the-json-name-for-protobuf-extension) is this an answer to your question?

   ```
   message TestMessage {
       string other_id = 2 [json_name="otherId"];
   }
   ```
2. `google.protobuf.Duration` should a string in json. Read comment [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/duration.proto#L94)

Comment: This will not work when using Golang `json` package which I think is what the OP requested. It will however work if you use protojson. But, protojson will only work if the entire json structure is a protobuf message. It bombs if one any nested part of the JSON is not a `proto.Message`